# Is Puzzle & Dragons available on Android in the UK?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

If I browse to the google play store on my phone I cannot find Puzzle & Dragons however I search. However I can see it on play.google.com. I seem to recall some time ago it was only available in Japan, then USA. Is this still the case? We Brits and fellow Europeans cannot get this game?

Comment: I ended up buying it on Nintendo 3DS !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Puzzle and Dragon's offical FAQ (EU Edition), it's Apple only:

http://www.gungho.jp/eu/pad/faq/en.html

The game can be played using the following devices:

[App Store] iPhone/iPod touch/iPad using iOS5.1 or higher.

- We cannot guarantee a quality play experience on devices other than recommended ones.
- Only for officially-released OSes.

The official Facebook page has the same information:

https://www.facebook.com/PuzzleAndDragonsEurope